# Menu content does not overflow it's parent in Safari for iOS

Tags: ios, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, overflow, mobile-safari

I have created a menu using Bootstrap 3 on a website. 
This menu works fine in every browser I have tested in, and at any screen size.

Except Safari on iOS, where the menu did not appear at all.

Using CSS, I forced the container of the menu to fill the width and to be 640px tall. Then I could see the menu. So the problem seems to be with overflow.

However, the containers parent and grandparent has an accumulated padding which makes no difference in any browser (that I have tested) except for in Safari on iOS. *This can  be seen in screetshot number 2.*

**Clearifying some terms**

*The menu* is refering to the `<ul>` element with id `header-menu`. This is marked RED in the screenshot below.

*The parent* is refering to the immidiate parent, with class `navbar-ex1-collapse`. This is marked BLUE in the screenshot below.

**Recreating the problem**

I was finally able to recreate the same problem in Chrome by adding `position: absolute;` to the parent.

**Screenshots**

[image: Screenshot of menu in Chrome]

[image: Screenshot of menu in Safari on iOS]

[image: Screenshot of the menu and container code]

**Check out the code snippet:**

```js
 (function($){
  $("#header-menu .menu-item-has-children > a, #header-menu .menu-item-has-children > span.after").on('click', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   if( $(this).parent().hasClass('hide-sub') ){
    $(this).parent().addClass("show-sub").removeClass("hide-sub");
   }else{
    $(this).parent().addClass("hide-sub").removeClass("show-sub");
   }
  });
  
  $("#header-menu .close-menu-button > span.before").on('click', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   if( $(this).parent().parent().parent().hasClass('hide-sub') ){
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().addClass("show-sub").removeClass("hide-sub");
   }else{
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().addClass("hide-sub").removeClass("show-sub");
   }
  });
 })(jQuery);
```

```css
@charset "utf-8";

@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css');


#header-menu {
  float: right
}




@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05);
    border: 0 none;
    border-radius: 0
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
    background-color: #d23479
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover .icon-bar,
  .navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus .icon-bar {
    background-color: #fff
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
  .navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
    background-color: #d23479
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-collapse,
  .navbar-default .navbar-form {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
    border: 0;
    box-shadow: none
  }
  .navbar-collapse {
    margin-top: 10px
  }
}
@media(max-width:991px) {
  .navbar-nav>li>a {
    line-height: 70px;
  }
  .nav>li {
    font-size: 35px;
  }
  .navbar-nav {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0px;
  }
}





/*meny*/

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  #header-menu .only-mobile,
  #header-menu a span {
    display: none !important;
  }
  #header-menu > li {
    position: static;
  }
  #header-menu > li > a {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  #header-menu > li > a:active {
    color: #d23479;
  }
  #header-menu > li > a:focus {
    color: white;
  }
  #header-menu > li > ul.sub-menu {
    display: block;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    min-height: 640px;
    max-height: 768px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    left: 0;
  }
  #header-menu > li > ul.sub-menu > li {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
  }
  #header-menu > li > ul.sub-menu > li > ul.sub-menu {
    display: table-row;
  }
  #header-menu > li > ul.sub-menu > li > ul.sub-menu > li {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 25%;
    padding: 15px;
  }
  #header-menu > li > ul.sub-menu > li > ul.sub-menu > li:first-of-type {
    padding: 15px 15px 15px 0;
  }
  #header-menu > li > ul.sub-menu > li > ul.sub-menu > li:last-of-type {
    padding: 15px 0 15px 15px;
  }
  #header-menu > li > ul.sub-menu > li.sub-menu-row:first-of-type > ul.sub-menu > li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 5px;
  }
  #header-menu > li > ul.sub-menu > li > ul.sub-menu > li > a {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: black;
    border-width: 0 0 1px 0;
    border-style: solid;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    font-weight: 600;
    border-color: #d23479;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
  #header-menu > li > ul.sub-menu > li > ul.sub-menu > li > ul.sub-menu > li {
    width: 100%;
  }
  #header-menu > li > ul.sub-menu > li > ul.sub-menu > li > ul.sub-menu > li > a {
    color: gray;
    font-size: 12px;
  }
  #header-menu .sub-menu-row {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
  #header-menu .sub-menu-row:nth-of-type(2) {
    margin-top: 50px;
    border-width: 1px 0 0 0;
    border-color: lightgray;
    border-style: solid;
  }
  #header-menu .sub-menu-row:nth-of-type(2) > ul.sub-menu > li > a {
    text-transform: none;
    font-weight: 300 !important;
    border: none;
  }
  #header-menu .contact a {
    color: #d23479 !important;
  }
  #header-menu [class*="icon-"]:before {
    font-size: 26px;
    color: #d23479;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 10px;
    position: relative;
  }
  #header-menu > .menu-item-has-children > span {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  #header-menu > .menu-item-has-children > span:after {
    margin: 0 0 0 5px;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  #header-menu > .menu-item-has-children.hide-sub > span.after:before {
    content: '';
    background-image: url('https://boxdev.no/box/wp-content/themes/box/icons/DropDown-Arrow.png');
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
  }
  #header-menu > .menu-item-has-children.show-sub > span.after:before {
    background: none;
    content: '×';
    font-size: 27px;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 1.2em;
    font-family: serif;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: #d23479;
  }
  #header-menu > .menu-item-has-children.hide-sub > .sub-menu {
    display: none;
  }
  #header-menu > .menu-item-has-children.show-sub > .sub-menu {
    display: block;
  }
  #header-menu .sub-menu .close-menu-button {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 130px;
  }
  #header-menu .sub-menu .close-menu-button span.before {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  #header-menu .sub-menu .close-menu-button span.before:before {
    content: '×';
    color: #d23479;
    font-size: 42px;
    font-family: serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 32px;
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
  }
  #header-menu .sub-menu .close-menu-button span.before:after {
    content: 'Lukk meny';
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #ccc;
    font-size: 12px;
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 991px) {
  #header-menu button.navbar-toggle {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 42px;
    height: 32px;
    background-color: #d23479;
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    right: 30px;
  }
  #header-menu button.navbar-toggle:before {
    content: '×';
    color: white;
    font-family: serif;
    font-size: 32px;
    vertical-align: top;
    line-height: 16px;
  }
  #header-menu {
    background-color: white;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 10;
    overflow: scroll;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding: 102px 20px 20px 20px;
  }
  #header-menu .only-computer {
    display: none !important;
  }
  #header-menu > li,
  #header-menu .sub-menu li {
    text-align: left;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  }
  #header-menu .show-sub > ul.sub-menu {
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  }
  #header-menu a {
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 1.4em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 400;
    padding: 0;
    color: #222;
    font-size: 18px;
  }
  #header-menu ul.sub-menu > li > ul.sub-menu > li > a {
    color: #444;
    font-size: 15px;
  }
  #header-menu ul.sub-menu > li > ul.sub-menu > li > ul.sub-menu > li > a {
    color: #666;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 300;
  }
  #header-menu > li > a:active,
  #header-menu > li.show-sub > a {
    color: #d23479;
  }
  #header-menu ul.sub-menu {
    padding-left: 15px;
  }
  #header-menu .menu-item-1350 > .sub-menu {
    padding: 0;
  }
  #header-menu .sub-menu-row {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
  #header-menu .sub-menu > li:first-of-type,
  #header-menu .sub-menu-row,
  #header-menu .bottom-contact-info,
  #header-menu .bottom-contact-info li {
    border: none !important;
  }
  #header-menu .menu-item-has-children.hide-sub span {
    display: none;
  }
  #header-menu .menu-item-has-children.hide-sub > a {} #header-menu .menu-item-has-children > a {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 22px 22px;
    background-position: 98% 50%;
  }
  #header-menu .menu-item-has-children.hide-sub > a {
    background-image: url('https://boxdev.no/box/wp-content/themes/box/icons/down-arrow-menu.png');
  }
  #header-menu .menu-item-has-children.show-sub > a {
    background-image: url('https://boxdev.no/box/wp-content/themes/box/icons/right-arrow-menu.png');
  }
  #header-menu .menu-item-has-children.hide-sub > .sub-menu {
    display: none;
  }
  #header-menu .menu-item-has-children.show-sub > .sub-menu {
    display: block;
  }
  #header-menu > li:first-of-type,
  #header-menu .bottom-contact-info > .sub-menu {
    border-top: 1px solid #d23479;
    padding: 0;
  }
  #header-menu .bottom-contact-info a {
    color: #333;
  }
  #header-menu [class*="icon-"]:before {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #d23479;
    margin: 0 10px;
    position: relative;
    text-transform: none;
  }
  #header-menu > .menu-item-has-children > span {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  #header-menu > .menu-item-has-children > span:after {
    margin: 0 0 0 5px;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  #header-menu .inactive > a,
  #header-menu .inactive > span,
  #header-menu a span {
    display: none;
  }
  #header-menu .logo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 30px;
    border: 0;
  }
  #header-menu .logo > a {
    background-image: url('https://boxdev.no/box/wp-content/themes/box/images/logo.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    height: 34px;
    width: 167px;
  }
}
/* Fixing the menu for Safari on iOS */

.dropdown-backdrop {
  position: static !important;
}
.navbar-ex1-collapse {
  z-index: 99999;
}
.collapse.in {
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 640px;
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  overflow: scroll;
  position: static !important;
}
#header-menu {
  z-index: 99999 !important;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <a href="#" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse" aria-expanded="false">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span> 
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse collapse" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 0px;">
    <ul id="header-menu" class="nav navbar-nav main_menu">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse"></button>
      <li id="menu-item-956" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-956"><span class="before"></span><a href="#prosjekter">Prosjekter</a><span class="after"></span>
      </li>
      <li id="menu-item-1502" class="hide-sub menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-1502"><span class="before"></span><a href="#tjenester">Tjenester</a><span class="after"></span>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li id="menu-item-1350" class="sub-menu-row inactive menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-1350"><span class="before"></span><a href="#"><span>Undermeny</span></a><span class="after"></span>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
              <li id="menu-item-1317" class="hide-sub menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-1317"><span class="before"></span><a href="#">Nettsteder</a><span class="after"></span>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                  <li id="menu-item-1503" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1503"><span class="before"></span><a href="#responsiv-hjemmeside">Responsiv Hjemmeside</a><span class="after"></span>
                  </li>
                  <li id="menu-item-1504" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1504"><span class="before"></span><a href="#nettbutikk">Nettbutikk</a><span class="after"></span>
                  </li>
                  <li id="menu-item-1318" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1318"><span class="before"></span><a href="#landingsider">Landingsider</a><span class="after"></span>
                  </li>
                  <li id="menu-item-1332" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1332"><span class="before"></span><a href="#">WordPress</a><span class="after"></span>
                  </li>
                  <li id="menu-item-1333" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1333"><span class="before"></span><a href="#">Webdesign</a><span class="after"></span>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li id="menu-item-1314" class="hide-sub menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-1314"><span class="before"></span><a href="#">Synlighet</a><span class="after"></span>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                  <li id="menu-item-1505" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1505"><span class="before"></span><a href="#google-annonsering">Google Annonsering</a><span class="after"></span>
                  </li>
                  <li id="menu-item-1335" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1335"><span class="before"></span><a href="#">Facebook Annonsering</a><span class="after"></span>
                  </li>
                  <li id="menu-item-1316" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1316"><span class="before"></span><a href="#sokemotoroptimalisering">Søkemotoroptimalisering</a><span class="after"></span>
                  </li>
                  <li id="menu-item-1507" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1507"><span class="before"></span><a href="#fa-flere-henvendelser">Få flere henvendelser</a><span class="after"></span>
                  </li>
                  <li id="menu-item-1315" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1315"><span class="before"></span><a href="#konverteringsoptimalisering">Konverteringsoptimalisering</a><span class="after"></span>
                  </li>
                  <li id="menu-item-1509" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1509"><span class="before"></span><a href="#forbedring-av-innhold">Forbedring av Innhold</a><span class="after"></span>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li id="menu-item-1338" class="hide-sub menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-1338"><span class="before"></span><a href="#">Hosting</a><span class="after"></span>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                  <li id="menu-item-1500" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1500"><span class="before"></span><a href="#hosting">Webserver / Webhotell/ E-post</a><span class="after"></span>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li id="menu-item-1340" class="hide-sub menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-1340"><span class="before"></span><a href="#">Support</a><span class="after"></span>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                  <li id="menu-item-1341" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1341"><span class="before"></span><a href="#">Driftsstatus server</a><span class="after"></span>
                  </li>
                  <li id="menu-item-1342" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1342"><span class="before"></span><a href="#">Support</a><span class="after"></span>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li id="menu-item-1349" class="sub-menu-row inactive only-computer menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-1349"><span class="before"></span><a href="#"><span>Kontaktinfo PC</span></a><span class="after"></span>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
              <li id="menu-item-1344" class="contact inactive menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1344"><span class="before"></span><a href="#">Kontakt oss:</a><span class="after"></span>
              </li>
              <li id="menu-item-1345" class="icon-phone menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1345"><span class="before"></span><a href="tel:+4799988999">+47 999 88 999</a><span class="after"></span>
              </li>
              <li id="menu-item-1346" class="icon-mail menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1346"><span class="before"></span><a href="mailto:mail@example.com">mail@example.com</a><span class="after"></span>
              </li>
              <li id="menu-item-1347" class="icon-mapmarker menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1347"><span class="before"></span><a href="#">Company address, 9999 Ziptown</a><span class="after"></span>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li id="menu-item-1528" class="only-computer close-menu-button menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1528"><span class="before"></span><a href="#"><span>Lukk meny</span></a><span class="after"></span>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li id="menu-item-24" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-24"><span class="before"></span><a href="#hvem-er-box-media">Hvem er Box Media</a><span class="after"></span>
      </li>
      <li id="menu-item-1501" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1501"><span class="before"></span><a href="#aktuelt">Aktuelt</a><span class="after"></span>
      </li>
      <li id="menu-item-100" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-100"><span class="before"></span><a href="#kontakt-oss">Kontakt oss</a><span class="after"></span>
      </li>
      <li id="menu-item-1527" class="bottom-contact-info only-mobile menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-1527"><span class="before"></span><a href="#"><span>Kontaktinfo mobil</span></a><span class="after"></span>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li id="menu-item-1522" class="icon-phone menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1522"><span class="before"></span><a href="tel:++4799988999">+47 999 88 999</a><span class="after"></span>
          </li>
          <li id="menu-item-1523" class="icon-mail menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1523"><span class="before"></span><a href="mailto:mail@example.com">mail@example.com</a><span class="after"></span>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li id="menu-item-1525" class="logo only-mobile menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-36 current_page_item menu-item-1525"><span class="before"></span><a href="#"><span>Hjem</span></a><span class="after"></span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). Although you have provided a [**link to an example or site**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the information @Paulie_D. I will update my question shortly.

Comment: hav you added the `viewport` meta tag

Answer (score 1):

Try explicitly setting the navbar positioning to relative. There seems to be a recurring bug with positioning elements for Safari on iOS.